# How to convert XML node contents to string in VBA?

Tags: xml, string, vba, nodes

I'm trying to populate a list box with all of the XML nodes in an XML file in one column of the listbox, and then have the value of the corresponding node in the second column of the listbox.

So, for example:

Column one | Column Two

firstname |   John

surname | Smith

(dreadful formatting, but just wanted to give you a rough idea)

I've accomplished the first part, and have listed all of the XML node names in one column, however I'm having difficulty with the latter part.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
Public Sub LoadDocument()
Dim xDoc As DOMDocument
Set xDoc = New DOMDocument
xDoc.validateOnParse = False
If xDoc.Load(filepath) Then

   DisplayNode xDoc.ChildNodes
Else
   ' The document failed to load.
   ' See the previous listing for error information.
End If
End Sub

Public Sub DisplayNode(ByRef Nodes As IXMLDOMNodeList)

   Dim xNode As IXMLDOMNode

   For Each xNode In Nodes
    If xNode.nodeName = "#text" Then

    Else
    With xnodeListBox
    .AddItem (xNode.nodeName)
    .list(.ListCount - 1, 1) = (xNode.nodevalue)
    End With
      If xNode.HasChildNodes Then
         DisplayNode xNode.ChildNodes
      End If
    End If
   Next xNode

End Sub
```

This line is the problem point:

```
.list(.ListCount - 1, 1) = (xNode.nodevalue)
```

Can anyone give me hand with this?

EDIT:

I believe I figured it out.

What I *think* happened is this: The first node would contain the entire contents of the document, so it would have an absurdly large amount of characters. This meant that the contents of the first node couldn't be stored, and with the previous code, wouldn't move onto the other nodes. This may just be a limitation specific to the XML files i'm dealing with.

To prevent that happening, I changed the code to this:

```
   Public Sub DisplayNode(ByRef Nodes As IXMLDOMNodeList)

   Dim xNode As IXMLDOMNode

   For Each xNode In Nodes
    If xNode.nodeName = "#text" Then

    Else
    With xnodeListBox
    .AddItem xNode.nodeName
    If (Len(xNode.nodeTypedValue) < 300) Then
    .list(row, 1) = xNode.nodeTypedValue
    End If
    row = row + 1
    End With
    End If

      If xNode.HasChildNodes Then
         DisplayNode xNode.ChildNodes
      End If
   Next xNode

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.AddItem xNode.nodeName & ""
.List(.ListCount-1, 1) = xNode.nodeValue & ""
```

The empty strings are added to cope with Null-values.

Comment: that returned a null value

Comment: Access, Excel or Word? If you add "John;Smith" as a test?

Comment: I'm using Excel, and doing:
`.AddItem("John" & ";" & "Smith")` works.

Comment: Ok, the proposed solutions only works in Access. Your code should be working in Excel although I would discard the braces (see modified code). What is the error message.

Comment: I'm not receiving an error message. With my original code, I have a type mismatch. With your code, it puts the same input in both sections of the listbox, whereas I need it to put the node name in one column, and the value of the node in the second column.

Comment: Is the message for your original code "Could not set the List property. Type mismatch."? This could be cause by a null-value. Try the modified code in my answer (adding the empty strings after the object properties).

Comment: Yes that's the error message. However the modified code is still only outputting the node name and not its value.

Comment: Have you set the List Box property ColumnCount to 2?

Comment: Yes, the list box property column count is 2

Comment: And you are sure that nodeValue has a value other than null. If you add the constant "Smith" instead of xNode.nodeValue & "" you don't see Smith?

Comment: It must be the null value being the problem. I can put in a string for the second column, i.e. `.List(.ListCount-1,1) = "test string"`, and it also works for assigning "test string" to a string variable. Hence the initial question of how to assign an xml node's contents to a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

Check value with **IsNull function**. *It returns a Boolean value that indicates whether an expression contains no valid data (Null).*

E.g. like this:

```
.List(row, 1) = IIf(IsNull(xNode.NodeValue), "NULL", xNode.NodeValue)
```

Complete example:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const xml As String = _
    "<ROOT>" & _
        "<NODE1>Val1</NODE1>" & _
        "<NODE2>Val2</NODE2>" & _
    "</ROOT>"

Public Sub LoadDocument()
    Dim xDoc As DOMDocument
    Set xDoc = New DOMDocument

    xDoc.validateOnParse = False

    Dim row As Integer
    row = 0

    If xDoc.LoadXML(xml) Then
       DisplayNode xDoc.ChildNodes, row
    Else
       ' The document failed to load.
       ' See the previous listing for error information.
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub DisplayNode(ByRef Nodes As IXMLDOMNodeList, row As Integer)

    Dim xNode As IXMLDOMNode

    With xnodeListBox
        For Each xNode In Nodes
            If xNode.nodeName = "#text" Then
                ' ...
            Else
                .AddItem
                .List(row, 0) = "nodeName:" & xNode.nodeName
                .List(row, 1) = "nodeValue:" & IIf(IsNull(xNode.NodeValue), "NULL", xNode.NodeValue)
                .List(row, 2) = "nodeTypedValue:" & IIf(IsNull(xNode.nodeTypedValue), "NULL", xNode.nodeTypedValue)
                row = row + 1

                If xNode.HasChildNodes Then
                    DisplayNode xNode.ChildNodes, row
                End If
            End If
        Next xNode
   End With

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    LoadDocument
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.xnodeListBox.ColumnCount = 3
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Dee, I'm getting null values even though there is data in the xml nodes. 
what's confusing is when I assign `xNode.nodeValue` to a string (xNodeContent) and `msgbox(xNodeContent)` it displays the value of the node, so it isn't null. When I tried to use the string in the `.list` statement I was given the same error of a type mismatch?

Comment: Could you post sample of your xml data you are using?